# How to pass login and password data for a web app to a desktop application without causing any security risks

Tags: c++, security, qt

So I want to do the following:
A person registers online and selects their login and password for a desktop and web application (same login and password for both applications)
They then download the desktop application (written in C++ with Qt as it's cross platform)
Then the login and password is automatically passed to the desktop application without the person needing to enter this data. The login and password is used to authenticate with the server.

Each version of the desktop application needs to be individually coded with the person's login and password based on the fact that they signed up on the web page.

So here is a more simple explanation:
1. The user signs up on the web site and choose login\password
2. The user download desktop client on his computer
3. The user runs desktop client (C++ binary) and it asks for a login/password from the step

I would like that software fill in login/password automatically on step 3 for the first time. Is it possible? How would it be done without security risks?

Comment: Update to the question. I am planning to solve the problem in a totally different way. Instead of the person signing up online, they will sign up ON THE SOFTWARE, and then the data will be sent online.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is, that anyone could execute the program and gain access to a user account. I would suggest using a one-time login for first authentification with random tokens and after the first start, get the user/password information through an ssl-connection. After that delete your one-time login token and replace it with the actual login.

I don't really know whether you're asking for precise code examples or just want to have a basic concept... But anyway, storing login-data in the application itself is a security risk.

Comment: Thanks. I think yes it's a security risk, but wondering if there is a way around the security risk. If there is a one time token, then how would that mitigate the risks? Not looking for precise code examples, just a general idea of how to do it. I have a team of 8 guys working on this project. Basically we are at the point of saying it can't be done, but I always tend to think there must be a way of doing it.

Comment: When you use a one time token, you generate it and the user downloads the application and probably executes it within few minutes. After that, a regular login is created and stored within the application data, so only one local copy exists containing the login information. The one time token is typically only accessible for few minutes, which makes it hard for an attacker to steal the information. Well it's just a little improvement... for more advanced security you could think about DRM used eg. in the App-Store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at HTTP Authentication?
I do not fully understand the download process of the QT app, but, if you use a Basic/Digest Authentication on your web server, propagating the authenticate token will be easy and safe.
Basic use a 64 base encoding, Digest a MD5 hashing. A lot of library implements those steps out there (Spring Security and Shiro in the Java world).

Answer (score 0):

I saw two ways:

- the server can provide a user with unique link for downloading installation package. The server patches that package by unique one-time password. So client will be able to login for a first time
- the browser collects some information about a user's computer. For example, IP, MAC, OS Version, etc. Then it calulate digital sign of the computer based on these data. The C++ binary do the same. You can use that digital sign as one-time password.